# How many 5-element subsets of [10] contain at least one of the members of [3]?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here [10] denotes the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} & in the same manner [3] denotes {1,2,3}.

I'm attempting to solve this for my combinatorics course. My method would be to solve 10 permutation 5, then divide by 3 factorial. I am choosing 5 elements from a set of 10, & at least 1 or 2 or 3 need to be in that set. I am confused how to make sure 1 or 2 or 3 are accounted for & something tells me dividing by 3 factorial is the wrong method.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Count the negation and subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 C 5 = 252

There are 252 ways to pick 5 things from 10 things.

7 C 5 = 21

There are 21 ways to pick 5 things from 7 things.

So, 252 - 21 = 231

There are 231 ways to pick 5 things from 10 things such that at least one of the 5 things is in a subset with 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

As [@vadim123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73324/vadim123) suggested, you can count all 5-elements subset of [10], minus the ones which don't contain any element of [3], basically the 5-elements subsets of {4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. So:

$\binom{10}{5}-\binom{7}{5}=\frac{10!}{5!(10-5)!}-\frac{7!}{5!(7-5)!}=231$